# Can I use the ## operation on JSON objects?

Tags: karate

Looking at the documentation it is straighforward how to use the ## operator on fields e.g

`* def data = { a: 'hello', b: null, c: null }
* def json = { foo: '#(data.a)', bar: '#(data.b)', baz: '##(data.c)' }
* match json == { foo: 'hello', bar: null }`

but what if I want to use it on a json object when there are no properties ? E.g. if I am doing something like

`* def data = { a: 'hello', b: null, c: null }
* def json = { foo: '#(data.a)', bar: '#(data.b)', jsonObject: {baz: '##(data.c)'} }
* match json == { foo: 'hello', bar: null }`

it is complaining that there is an empty object

```
actual: {foo=hello, bar=null, jsonObject={}}, expected: {foo=hello, bar=null}
```

and putting ##{baz: '##(data.c)'} or ##({baz: '##(data.c)'}) as jsonObject value does not work as ## is not recognized correctly.

What is the correct syntax?Or is there another way to do what I am describing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a somewhat complex conditional substitution. Here's how you can do it:

```
* def data = { a: 'hello', b: null, c: null }
* def temp = data.c ? { baz: data.c } : null
* def json = { foo: '#(data.a)', bar: '#(data.b)', jsonObject: '##(temp)' }
* match json == { foo: 'hello', bar: null }
```

Maybe you are over-complicating things, and all you need is this:

```
* def data = { a: 'hello', b: null, c: null }
* def json = { foo: '#(data.a)', bar: '#(data.b)' }
* if (data.c) json.jsonObject = ({ baz: data.c })
* match json == { foo: 'hello', bar: null }
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your response but in your example what you are doing is using the ## operator on a field(that is well explained in the doc and showed in my first example): however my question is if you can use something like that on an empty json array(see "jsonArray" on my second example). Sorry if this was not clear enough.

Comment: @Sorcio it is not clear. I don't see any array. where are the square brackets ?

Comment: Sorry my bad you are completely right: I will edit the question. My question is if you can use the ## operator on an object(not an array) that has no fields to filter it so that the following works  * def data = { a: 'hello', b: null, c: null }
* def json = { foo: '#(data.a)', bar: '#(data.b)', jsonObject: {baz: '##(data.c)'} }
* match json == { foo: 'hello', bar: null }

Comment: @Sorcio I am lost. please edit your question

Comment: Edited sorry for this mess!

Comment: Thanks Peter, awesome. I thought it was something simpler but your response makes perfect sense. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sorcio ask a new question please

Comment: Done here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68497165/behavior-of-operator-on-json-objects