# Behavior of ## operator on JSON objects

Tags: karate

the question is strictly related to the solution that was proposed here [Can I use the ## operation on JSON objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68482628/can-i-use-the-operation-on-json-objects) that suggested to use the ## operator to evaluate if JSON object are null.
The proposed solution was to use some conditional substition so

```
* def data = { a: 'hello', b: null, c: null }
* def temp = data.c ? { baz: data.c } : null
* def json = { foo: '#(data.a)', bar: '#(data.b)', jsonObject: '##(temp)' }
* match json == { foo: 'hello', bar: null }
```

This solution works perfectly if data.c is equal to null, but it has issues if data.c is set to some value e.g.

```
 * def data = { a: 'hello', b: null, c: 'world' }
 * def temp = data.c ? { baz: data.c } : null
 * def json = { foo: '#(data.a)', bar: '#(data.b)', jsonObject: '##(temp)' }
 * match json == { foo: 'hello', bar: null, jsonObject:{baz:'world'}}
```

is failing because

```
 actual: '##(temp)', expected: {baz=world}.
```

In other words it seems that the ## operator is not able to recognize correctly the json object in the temp variable. Please notice that the solution if working perfectly if the temp variable evaluates to null. Am I doing something wrong?If not is there some workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try Karate 1.1.0.RC5 because I think this is fixed in that release.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I am using a framework that has karate 0.9.5 in it. Need to ask the author of the framework to update it but if it is a known bug I am glad that is fixed. I suppose that there is no workaround to make it work for 0.9.5 right?

Comment: @Sorcio yes, sorry there is no issue id for this, because it was reported to me directly. unfortunately there is no clean work-around other than setting JSON key-values by hand, which I think is what you should be doing based on your examples here - but maybe you have a more complicated scenario in your real tests

Comment: Thanks yes this was a simpler example that the real world one; I'll try to get and use the latest release. Thanks again for you support!

Comment: @Sorcio no problem. do let me know once you get a chance to try the new version. please take a look at the updated documentation (not released yet) but you can see here, note the new section that refers to `trying to pre-define schema snippets` in case you need that behavior: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop#remove-if-null

Comment: Sure I'll let you know and I'll check that section as well. Thanks again

Comment: Hi @Peter Thomas quick follow-up on that: I finally was able to test it in Karate 1.1.0 and I confirm the issue has been fixed. Thanks for that!